# I cant import function_tree to my pubspec.yaml(flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an eror when I try to import this package into my `pubspec.yaml` and I do not know why is that. Could you please help me?

**The Error:**

> `Because nmber4v3 depends on function_tree >=0.8.0-dev.1 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-259.9.beta <3.0.0, version solving failed. pub get failed (1; Because nmber4v3 depends on function_tree >=0.8.0- dev.1 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-259.9.beta <3.0.0, version solving failed.) exit code 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think it because function_tree in version >=0.8.0-dev.1 is support null safety and the dart version you have is not support null safety yet so you have two options

the first one is to import function_tree with version 0.7.0 or less

and the second one is upgrade flutter which will support null safety and update your project and now you can use any version you need

Comment: is one of them better

Comment: if your app is already have all packages support null safety then you can upgrade your app to null safety and migrate it is the best choice , but if some packages not support null safety yet use the first choice till all packages you use support it